# CSS wont load image on server

Tags: html, css, image, server

I have html/css image slider.My images is loaded from css and all works on localhost but on server images is not loaded...

```
background-image: url("assets/images/slider/slider1.jpg");
```

all other images on css is load successfully, only this cant....like this one:

```
background-image: url("assets/images/card2.jpg");
```

Comment: What error code/message does the network tab of the developer tools in your browser show for that image?

Comment: hope you uploaded all same folder and images also

Comment: No errors for image... only Will-change memory consumption is too high. Budget limit is the document surface area multiplied by 3 (881280 px). Occurrences of will-change over the budget will be ignored.

Comment: I extract from zip.It's all the same as on localhost...

Comment: OK, I get it. The problem is that the folder name was Slider but server only accept slider with small s....

Comment: But then the network tab of the dev console in your browser would have displayed a loading error for the givn file, a 404 or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Some servers require image urls to be case-sensitive to load that image. Make sure the names of all folders and image files are lower-case (as is in your requirement). Also check if the card2 file extension .jpg or .jpeg

One more thing you can try is adding a "/" at the beginning of url like

Change:
`background-image: url("assets/images/card2.jpg");`

to:
`background-image: url("/assets/images/card2.jpg");`

Hope it helps.